# Update page data without refreshing the page using Jquery - Json

Tags: jquery, json

I have a script that calls another script every 10 seconds to get a Json string. The resulting data in the Json string populates a data table generated by Jquery. This works in a fashion as far as it displays the data but does not update the data when the content of the Json string changes. The screen data does update if I manually refresh the browser. Am I doing this wrong and if so any anyone see where I have made any mistakes.

Json

```
[{"data":[{"ClientImageName":"British-Airways.png","ClientName":"British Airways","RoomName":"Room 7","RoomFromTime":"06:00","RoomToTime":"18:00"},{"ClientImageName":"logo.png","ClientName":"Name 12","RoomName":"Room 12","RoomFromTime":"07:00","RoomToTime":"19:00"}]}]
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
function get_data() {
  $.getJSON("get_data.php", function(json){
  json = json[0].data;
  var tr ;
  for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {

      tr = $('<tr/>');
      tr.css("border-bottom","2px solid #FFF");
     tr.append("<td width='15%'><div class='clientimage'><img src='../../../../conf_images/boards/" + json[i].ClientImageName + "'></></div></td>");
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='clientname-text'>" + json[i].ClientName + "</div></td>");
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='roomname-text'>" + json[i].RoomName + "</div></td>");
      tr.append("<td width='33%'><div class='time-text'>" + json[i].RoomFromTime + " - " + json[i].RoomToTime + "</div></td>");

   $('table').append(tr);
  }
  });

}

get_data();
setInterval(get_data,10000)
});
```

Many thnks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using append(). Append will attach data to the end of existing data, it will not overwrite it.

You will either need to destroy your table before each reload, or populate the table cells using "html()" or "text()" as they will overwrite the existing data as opposed to "appending" to it.

Comment: thanks for your reply, where/what in my current code would I need to change. I tried changing the 'append' to 'html' and that did not work.

Comment: Honestly, looking at your code, the easiest way to do this is to just destroy the table rows and rebuild them with your new data on each load. I believe you can just use the .remove() method on the table rows right before you you reconstruct it with the new data.

something like this $('table tr').destroy();

Comment: if I put $('.table1 tr').destroy(); just before  var tr ; I get an error in the console: TypeError: $(...).destroy is not a function. Am I putting this in the right place?

Comment: Hi all, can anyone help with this issue. Many thanks.

Comment: hi again and sorry to bother you. Could you please explain how I would change my code to force the on screen data to be overwritten rather than appended to. Many thank in advance.